# Table relationship with other table, should I join only one if other tables are related

Tags: database, normalization

I have 4 tables namely:

```
tbl_users
tbl_college
tbl_courses
tbl_sections
```

`tbl_users` contains of course, `username`, `password`

What if I wanted to fetch all the information regarding a certain user, including:

1. What college does he/she belong (e.g. **college of engineering** or **college of business administration**)
2. What course is he/she is taking (e.g. **bachelor of science in civil engineering** or **bachelor of science in marketing**)
3. What section is he/she into (e.g. **CBC** or **ITED**)

if `tbl_courses` is setup like this :

```
tbl_courses (id, course_name, college_id)
```

where `college_id` refers to the `tbl_college.id`

and tbl_sections is setup like this :

```
tbl_sections(id, section_name, course_id)
```

where `course_id` refers to the `tbl_course.id`

What should I do to select all those information related to the **users** which in this case are students that have `username`, `password`, `college`, `course`, `section`

What I have in mind is that I could create another table namely : `tbl_user_section`, like this :

```
 CREATE TABLE tbl_user_section (user_id INTEGER NOT NULL, section_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
 FOREIGN KEY user_id REFERENCES users(id),
 FOREIGN KEY section_id REFERENCES sections(id))
```

So that I can have a table which holds who is on what section. Also by putting it that way in my opinion I could easily do joins to fetch related information:

```
SELECT tbl_users.username, tbl_sections.section_name FROM tbl_users 
INNER JOIN tbl_user_section ON tbl_users.id = tbl_user_section.user_id 
INNER JOIN tbl_sections ON tbl_sections.id = tbl_user_section.section_id
```

The problem I encountered recently with this kind of setup is that if a user is not yet in a section, when I try to query all the users with that code above, that user will not be selected, otherwise not shown.

Also with this kind of setup I could probably do this

```
SELECT tbl_users.username, tbl_sections.section_name,
tbl_courses.course_name, tbl_colleges.college_name FROM tbl_users 
INNER JOIN tbl_user_section ON tbl_users.id = tbl_user_section.user_id 
INNER JOIN tbl_sections ON tbl_sections.id = tbl_user_section.section_id
INNER JOIN tbl_courses ON tbl_courses.id = tbl_sections.course_id
INNER JOIN tbl_colleges ON tbl_college.id = tbl_courses.college_id
```

To fetch those information included in the query.

In your opinion what other problems you can see from the setup I've created?

Is it wiser to just have the `section_id` field in the `tbl_users instead of creating a separate table like I did?

What if I have types of users, should I be doing the same(separate a table for user types) and have a `tbl_user_type` or just have them in the same table `tbl_users`

Suppose this is a big project, what would you choose?

Answer (score 2):

If you're having trouble getting a user to show up because they're missing from one or more tables, you can use an `OUTER JOIN` to have them appear, with NULL values in the columns which would come from those tables. So a student with no section would have a NULL value for section_name, but still have all other information intact.

Comment: +1 for answering and removing my confusing. waiting for more answers